# Use project module version in gomacro

Tags: go, jupyter-notebook, go-modules

I am not able to make `gomacro`/`gophernotes` use downloaded golang packages.

I have a project that is using modules where I have a `go.mod`/`go.sum`.

Before starting the gomacro instance I’ve downloaded all the project pkgs, but when I try to use any of the downloaded pkgs I see that gomacro download the latest version of that pkg.

```
    $ ls /go/pkg/mod/github.com/sirupsen/
    logrus@1.0.5  <- module version

    $ go version
    go version go1.15.1 linux/amd64

    $ env | grep go
    GOPATH=/go
    PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
    ...

    $ gomacro
    gomacro> import "github.com/sirupsen/logrus" 
    // debug: looking for package "github.com/sirupsen/logrus" ...
    // debug: compiling "/go/src/gomacro.imports/github.com/sirupsen/logrus/logrus.go" ...
    go: finding module for package github.com/sirupsen/logrus
    go: found github.com/sirupsen/logrus in github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.7.0
    gomacro>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `gomacro` doesn't have a means to indicate which module dependencies should be used; see https://github.com/cosmos72/gomacro/issues/82.

https://golang.org/issue/32337 proposes that we add some means to resolve packages from the existing module cache (probably by a `GOPROXY` environment variable setting). That would probably make it easier to get the behavior you're looking for here.